# Youtube-like video control bar in the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In the youtube app there's a possibility to collapse video into a small preview window with a playback and controls while you navigating in the different parts of the app. By tapping on the window you can always switch to full screen mode again.

I wonder: what't the best approach to implement similar functionality? For now I see few options but I'm not very well aware of the implications of these options.

*Note: I have an iPhone tabbar based app.*

1. Create a popover modal view controller, that is presented on top of current navigation stack in a current tab
2. Create a view and stick it to the bottom of the screen.
3. Create a view in bounds of a tabbar controller
4. Create a modal view controller embedded in tabbar controller.

Just from the list I suspect that using a specialized UIView (2) would be the worst possible way to do this. But I don't know about the rest. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That feature is called Picture In Picture or Picture In Graphics (depends if it's available "outside the app"). There are a few GitHub that propose such an implementation, you can get inspiration there, now that you have the terms to search for.

Comment: @Larme I guess I should've mentioned that I'm targeted for an iPhone solution. Plus I'm not looking for exact video playback functionality.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/malt03/PictureInPicture